# How to deal with sessionStorage locally in FF (for testing)

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sessionstorage

I'm trying to write tests for all my JS, and the tests (I'm using Jasmine) are run locally in the browser. Due to security restraints(?) sessionStorage does not work locally (viewing file:///... in the browser) in Firefox.

Quick example:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

This gives "Error: Operation is not supported".

I tried overriding window.sessionStorage with my own mock methods, but with no luck.

The only solution I have at the moment is to put everything related to sessionStorage inside a try/catch block.

Any suggestions for how to best handle this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` seems to work with this, you can mock `sessionStorage` use it:

```
var mockup = function() {
  var table = {};
  return {
    getItem: function(key) {
      return table[key];
    },
    setItem: function(key, value) {
      table[key] = value.toString();
    },
    clear: function() {
      table = {};
    }
  };
}();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: mockup });
// should output "Object { getItem=function(), setItem=function(), clear=function()}"
console.log(window.sessionStorage);
```

but this mockup doesn't work with the **indexer** of `sessionStorage` (`window.sessionStorage[key] = value`) [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to build the `mockup` object.

Comment: getItem should return NULL when the value is not present. So it should be `return items[key] ? items[key] : null`

Answer (score 0):

You get local mocking automatically if you use: http://nbubna.github.io/store/